# Comparing the value of .image?

Tags: vb.net, image

```
    Public Sub P71_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles P71.Click
        If P71red = True Then
            P71.Image = Image.FromFile("rs.png")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub P62_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles P62.Click
        If P71.Image Is Image.FromFile("rs.png") Then
            P62.Image = Image.FromFile("r.png")
            P62.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            P71.Image = Nothing
        ElseIf P71.Image Is Image.FromFile("r.png") Then
            P71.Image = Image.FromFile("g.png")
        Else
            P71.Image = Image.FromFile("gs.png")
        End If
        If P71.Image Is Nothing Then
            P71.Image = Image.FromFile("rk.png")
        End If
```

So, what has happened is that I'm trying to display `r.png` when `rs.png` is the imag; however, I am not sure why the line `If P71.Image Is Image.FromFile("rs.png") Then` is not working when the current image is `rs.png` from the `p71_click` function?

I have run a test, as you can see, and all it comes up with is `gs.png`. So I am confused, as it is not `nothing` because it would've showed `rk.png`, but it is not any of the other options.

Comment: You're comparing References, not the objects' content or anything else. When you store an Image in an object, you can compare the Reference of the object with another for equality. The source Image is not relevant anymore. Two objects that store the same image File have two distinct References, so the equality comparison results in `false`. Use a class object with properties that describe an Image, so you can also define a custom comparer that returns `true` when, e.g., the source file is the same.

Comment: A quick & easy way to do what you want is to just fill in the `.image`'s `.tag` field with the name of the file you put in it and compare the `.tag` field instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `.tag` property:

```
Public Sub P71_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles P71.Click

  If P71red = True Then

    P71.Image = Image.FromFile("rs.png")
    P71.Tag = "rs.png"

  End If

End Sub

Public Sub P62_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles P62.Click

  If P71.Tag = "rs.png" Then

    P62.Image = Image.FromFile("r.png")
    P62.Tag = "r.png"
    P62.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

    P71.Image = Nothing
    P71.Tag = String.Empty

  ElseIf P71.Tag = "r.png" Then

    P71.Image = Image.FromFile("g.png")
    P71.Tag = "g.png"

  Else

    P71.Image = Image.FromFile("gs.png")
    P71.Tag = "gs.png"

  End If

  If P71.Image Is Nothing Then

    P71.Image = Image.FromFile("rk.png")
    P71.Tag = "rk.png"

  End If

End Sub
```